# Networking How User Know Host Name is changed

Tags: networking

Suppose i book mark one site in my browser with www.abc.com after some days this host name change with ww.xyz.com.My question is how user automatically know this host name is changed?
I don't know my question having meaning or not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand too clearly, but if you've "bookmarked the site in your browser", then you must be serving HTTP. Therefore, you can just issue a **301 Moved Permanently** header to clients who connect, which tells the clients to update their bookmarks to your new site, "ww.xyz.com".

Comment: my question is if i change host name then my host name with old book mark is it work or not? if yes how if no how?

Comment: if you maintain both websites, and redirect your old one to your new one, then it will work. If you delete your old website without redirecting, obviously your visitors will be visiting a void, and won't know where to go.

Comment: is their any functionality in DNS or router to aware of this changing Host Name? sorry my question is tricky i have no much knowledge of networking...

Comment: @viky, which part of the DNS? The DNS is an entire system. Do you mean the server side, DNS resolution services or the client's?

Comment: @vicky, unless you have some kind of resident application on the client's side, there is no way to do this. Otherwise it would be too easy to write malware that redirect's a user's http://facebook.com or http://yourbank.com to some rogue site.